# Finite Set Induction

Tags: logic, set-theory, induction

Let A be a set and let $FS(A)$ be the set of all finite subsets of $A$. Then to prove a formula of the form

$$(\forall S \in FS(A))(Q(S))$$

it is sufficiently to prove the following two formulae:

1. $Q(\emptyset)$; (the basis of induction)
2. $(\forall S \in FS(A), x \in A)(Q(S) \rightarrow Q(S \cup \{x\}))$. (the inductive step)

Does this induction principle have a special name? Maybe, Finite Set Induction?

If it has a name, please provide a reference to the first use.

Comment: Sounds like plain old induction (on cardinality).

Comment: @André Nicolas. Yes, formulas of this form can be proved by mathematical induction on cardinality of S. But such a proof will be a little lengthier.

Comment: Not quite. Seems to be saying you can add an element, and it will still be true. Although you could do it with carnality, this approach seems different.

Comment: I would be surprised if a special name had been given to this specific item. Maybe somewhere by someone looking at connection between set theory with negation of Axiom of Infinity and first-order Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: @PyRulez: Surely doing it with carnality would be a bit risqué! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is really just induction over a well-founded set.

> **Definition.** We say that $(X,R)$ is a well-founded if whenever $A\subseteq X$ is non-empty, $A$ has an $R$-minimal element.

(Assuming the axiom of choice, this is equivalent to stating that there is no infinite $R$-decreasing sequence in $X$.)

It's not difficult to see that $FS(A)$ is well-founded under $\subseteq$. So we can utilize the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $(X,R)$ is a well-founded partial order, and $\varphi$ is a property such that for every $x\in X$ it holds:
>   $$(\forall y(y\mathrel R x\rightarrow\varphi(y)))\rightarrow\varphi(x),$$
>   then $\forall x\in X.\varphi(x)$.

Now it's not hard to see that the conditions that you gave are exactly sufficient for this. It's true vacuously for $\varnothing$, being the minimal element. The second condition assures that it holds for the singletons, and so for pairs, and so on and so forth.

There's nothing very special about it. In fact, a lot of times when we use strong induction on the natural numbers, we actually use this sort of induction on a different relation which is well-founded.

For example, consider the usual proof that every natural number is $1$ or it has a prime divisor. The relation $m\mathrel R n\iff m\mid n$ is well-founded, and we really do the induction on that order, rather than on the usual order of the natural numbers.

Comment: @Asaf.Of course, (almost?) every principle of induction can be deduced from the principle of well-founded induction. But sometimes a principle of induction deserves a special name. For example, look at Defnition 2 (Principle of Lexicographic Path Induction). The Principle
of Lexicographic Path Induction is the principle of well-founded induction with
the LPO as the well-founded ordering. (in http://www.itu.dk/~carsten/papers/cutbylpo.pdf)

Comment: I have never heard that term before. Naming is easy, but the question is whether or not the name will stick. In this case I don't believe any name would really stick. But go ahead.

Comment: Please, replace in your answer in "It's not difficult to see that FS(A) is well-founded under ⊆" the symbol "⊆" on a symbol of strict inclusion.

Comment: Victor, I agree that it's more common to use strict orders when talking about well-founded relations, but for reflexive partial orders the notion of minimal element is just slightly different ($\forall x.x\leq y\rightarrow x=y$ for $y$ minimal; whereas in a strict relation $\forall x.x\nless y$ states that $y$ is minimal).

Comment: How about we call it "Single Element Addition Induction".

Answer (score 1):

Note a full answer, but here is a proof that is works (by regular induction!):

Base Case: For the empty elements in $FS(A)$ your base case proves that $Q$ holds.

Induction Step: Assume $Q$ holds for elements of $FS(A)$ of cardinality $k$. Select an arbitary element of cardinality $k+1$ called $\eta$. Also, select a random element $x$. Now we take $\eta / \{x\}$ This has cardinality $k$, and therefore $Q$ holds for it. By your induction step, it holds for $\eta$.

$$\blacksquare$$